# I have got BUILD FAILURE result when executing command

Tags: windows, maven, cmd, rest-assured

I am receiving error messages when trying to create a maven project through by executing the below command, in cmd.exe.

```
mvn archetype:genrate -DgroupId=demoProject -DartifactId=Mavenjava -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false'

    

    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  0.500 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-21T11:49:24+05:30
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Could not find goal 'genrate' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1 among available goals crawl, create-from-project, generate, help, integration-test, jar, update-local-catalog -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a Typo mistake and Maven shows error msg clearly. `Could not find goal 'genrate'`

`mvn archetype:genrate` --> `mvn archetype:generate`

Comment: Thank you! @lucas yes you are right, but now I have done so many thing with my exisitng project and now whole project get corrupted, seriosly I don' know how to fix this blunder

Comment: Hi @lucas-nguyen-17 I have posted another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75802018/getting-error-in-whole-exisitng-projectrest-assured 

could you please suggested me required steps.

Thanks! in advance